# What's the best way to determine the working directory for UNIX process using 'ps'?

Tags: command-line, shell-script, process, ps, ruby

I am running a Ruby command line script (`rufus.sh`)which ultimately calls `Thread.new`, which spawns a UNIX process as shown below. I run this script for more than 1 directory as the output of the `ps` command shows below. The last (right most) column below is `COMMAND` (`COMD`) which is essentially  the name of the process. The problem is that `COMMAND` doesn't include the working directory (the current directory when the process was launched). What is the best way to figure that out or include it in `COMMAND`? Thanks, Chirag

```
ps -ef | grep runner
web       7532     1  0 Oct08 ?        00:02:08 /usr/local/bin/ruby ./script/runner ./config/jobs/control.rb critical_alert start
web      21114     1  1 Oct09 ?        02:49:28 /usr/local/bin/ruby ./script/runner ./config/jobs/control.rb task start
web      19028     1  1 10:45 pts/0    00:00:34 /usr/local/bin/ruby ./script/runner ./config/jobs/control.rb task start
web      19029     1  0 10:45 pts/0    00:00:10 /usr/local/bin/ruby ./script/runner ./config/jobs/control.rb critical_alert start
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if that answers your question, but the `pwdx` could give you the current working directory of any process.

Like this:

```
pwdx <PID>
```

You could also do what Ulrich Schwarz said and run

```
ls -l /proc/PID/cwd
```

Comment: Note that @Chirag asked for *source directory*, not for *current working directory*.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you will find it as the target of `/proc/(pid)/cwd`. It looks like it, but I'm not very at home in `/proc`.

Comment: Note that @Chirag asked for *source directory*, not for *current working directory*.

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't a necessity to have all the other info, you could try this:

```
ps -ef | grep runner | awk {'print$8'} | xargs which
```

It will grab the eighth column of `ps -ef` (this is the `COMD` column on my OS X machine; you may need to change this) and run it through `which`.

This works on my machine as demonstrated here:

```
$ ps -ef | grep grep
mfc      25780 21222  0 11:54 pts/5    00:00:00 grep grep

$ ps -ef | grep grep | awk {'print$8'} 
grep

$ ps -ef | grep grep | awk {'print$8'} | xargs which
/bin/grep
```